# Adding delay in assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to make the computer count to some high number to create a delay for some other part of the program. However, for some reason I can't set the count value to really high, it gives me an "expression out of range" error.

Code:

```
delay:       

        CMP     R5, #0x0009 ;THIS is the value that needs to be high
        BEQ     loop
        ADD     R5, R5, #1

        B       delay
```

How do I set that count limit to, say, 999999(dec)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the value into a register, then compare to that register:

```
    MOV R4, #999999 ; assuming ARM syntax and support for the MOV pseudo-op

delay:

    CMP R5, R4
    BEQ loop
    ADD R5, R5, #1
    B delay
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, although why can't I set the value straight to the register? What's the difference between having the same value loaded into either the memory or the register?

Answer (score 0):

ARM supports 8bit pattern that can be rotated by even number of bits<32 as immediate value in second operand. Better first load that value in some other register and then compare. Refer links for explanation:
[link1](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/CIHIDDID.html) 
and
[link2](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/CIHBEAGE.html)

Try this code:

```
    LDR R6,=999999
delay:       

    CMP     R5, R6 
    BEQ     loop
    ADD     R5, R5, #1

    B       delay
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
ADD     R5, R5, #1
```

by

```
ADDS     R5, R5, #1
```

Comment: The OP is using `CMP`, so the question was not related to `ADD` not updating the status register. The question was about how to compare a register against a large constant.